# Call outer function from click event handler in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic, pointer-arithmetic

I was struggled with a javascript question which can be simplified as following:

The real issue is more complicated with Ajax callback and auto list.  Based on my real requirement, I do need to call outer function from click event handler.  I just want to avoid the handler being called recursively.

JS:

```
test();

function test() {
    $('#btnTest').on('click', function () {
        console.log('button clicked');
        test();
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<button id="btnTest" class="btn btn-danger">Test</button>
```

The issue here is, when I first click the test button, the message will show once.  The second time I clicked the button, it will show twice.  The third time I clikced the button, it will show four times!  And then 8, 16, etc.  I think it's a basic programming logic, but still I don't know how to fix it.  I do need to call the outer function from the `OnClick` listener.  Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `test()` attaches a listener to your button. But you also call `test()` inside the listener added by `test()`. So every time you click, you will add _another_ listener.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually you can use `one` function.

```
test();

function test() {
    $('#btnTest').one('click', function () {
        console.log('button clicked');
        test();
    });
}
```

Please check it here: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wLues86q/)

Comment: Thank you @luke, you save my life.

Answer (score 3):

Don't make `test` hook up the event, because you're repeatedly hooking it up, every time `test` is executed.

Insetad:

```
$('#btnTest').on('click', test);

function test() {
    console.log('button clicked');
}
```

Comment: Hi Crowder, I understand to do like you said will avoid the repeated trigger of the log();  But in my situation(which is more complicated), I do need to call the test() from the onclick handler function.  Inside the test(), I do some setup for the button, then I need to reset the onclick.  What I'm looking for is that is there a way to do something inside the onclick to break the hook.

Comment: @Vigor: Use [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off). But if you're having to do that a lot, odds are there's a bigger issue that could be solved in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're calling `test();` **inside** of itself. It's performing recursion.

This should work. No need to wrap the binding in the function name also.

```
function test() {
    // Logic
};

$('#btnTest').on('click', function () {
    console.log('button clicked');
    test();
});
```

Comment: It isn't recursion, really. I suppose it's how academic you look at it or something. `test()` is called in the _listener_ it adds, so it's not directly calling itself.

Comment: Yeah you're right, completely overlooked the fact that it's inside the listener so I see your point.

Answer (score 0):

- On one event you are calling two things at a time.

USE

```
function test() {
    console.log('button clicked');
}
```

OR

```
$('#btnTest').on('click', function () {
    console.log('button clicked');
});
```

Comment: If you call `test()` from `test()`, it will call `test()` on `test()` call, and so on...

Comment: Sorry, i thought it's your requirement. let me edit my answer.